# Rails + Elastic Beanstalk: Abort deployments when database migration fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, database-migration

I've got a Rails 5/Ruby 2.3 app running on Elastic Beanstalk. I want deployments to abort when a database migration fails.

My `RAILS_SKIP_MIGRATIONS` is set to `false`, so migrations execute when deployment. However, I had an issue where one migration failed but the deployment completed. This of course resulted in several 500 afterwards.

I've considered writing an ebextension which runs on post-deployment and checks whether there's an issue. If there is, then I rollback to the previous app version. However, I'm not sure if this approach is the right one.